# Where can I ask questions about concepts?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

I have a working prototype in Python and want to port it to Java. Where can I ask questions on whether the approach I'm using is actually a good one and get feedback on it?

Comment: Check the duplicate, if your question is a conceptual software development question, [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions) is where you should ask it. But please read the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly before asking, just to make sure your question is suitable for the site.

Comment: thanks, i think i will try the programmers exchange, since according to this FAQ it is the place to be.

Comment: If in doubt between [programmers.SE] and [cs.SE], think of the kind of answer you want: that by a programmer or that by a (computer) scientist?